# Count the number of times the file was changed in the local repository with LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#

I have a function which gives me the name of the commit and the names of the files that were changed

```
var repo = new Repository("D:/Total");
foreach (Commit commit in repo.Commits)
{
    foreach (var parent in commit.Parents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", commit.Sha, commit.MessageShort);
        foreach (TreeEntryChanges change in repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parent.Tree,
                commit.Tree))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", change.Status, change.Path);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Question: How to count the number of times the file in all commits was changed in the local repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can do it:

```
var fileName = ".gitignore";  // relative (from repo root) file path
var i = 0;
foreach (var commit in repo.Commits)
{
    foreach (var parent in commit.Parents)
    {
        foreach (var change in repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parent.Tree, commit.Tree))
        {
            if (change.Path == fileName)
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("File {0} was changed {1} times.", fileName, i);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank. But this allows me to see the file changes in only 1 directory(var repo = new Repository("D:/Total");), and not for the entire project ..